# Debug NX Executor

Tags: webpack, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nxjs

Currently, my setup: `@nrwl/webpack` + `withReact` and `withNx` plugins -- is exporting CSS files with hashes. For my specific project, we need to have files without hashes. We can strip the hashes after building, but that's really just a workaround. I tried using the standard approach of adding this to `webpack.config.js`:

```
cssFilename: '[name].css'
```

That doesn't work for some reason and I can't figure out what the issue is. Does anyone with deeper NX and Webpack knowledge have a heuristic on how to properly debug this type of misconfiguration?

Comment: Question needs more focus. Specifically on misconfigurations using Nx Console with Reloading helps (learned this from Isaac Mann during Nx office hours [part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ki2eOXvh2Sw) and [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACiVWX7K5ro). Is there not a standard way to test webpack config separate to the executor (I'm not familar)?

Comment: Thanks for the links @AndrewAllen! Edited, per your suggestion